# Wordpress menu issue on IE!

Tags: wordpress, menu, internet-explorer

So I am building a site for a client. The problem is the menu I made doesn't work on IE. Here's the site: http://robertnogueira.com

You'll see that the topmost menu isn't where it is supposed to be..

I know this could be a very simple problem to fix. But since I am new to web development I really can't find a way to fix it...

Please help me figure it out..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CSS conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to target IE and change `ul#page-menu` css.

You should work on getting the right `margin-top` for `ul#page-menu`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but all margins are set to zero already.. :(

Comment: well then even it's not the perfect solution, you still can give negative values to margins ;)

Comment: I tried that but it ruins everything on other browsers.. It could end up unusable on all browsers except, well, IE. 

Sorry for being so stupid... :-(

Comment: wow, just placed ul#page-menu:margin-top:0px; and the bug is gone! thanks :-)

Comment: In case you don't know, it an answer was helpful to you, you should +1 it and accept it if it was the answer you used to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is fix your code errors, like the broken `<div id="header" ">` tag that's probably the cause of the menu problems. See your [[Invalid]Markup Validation of  robertnogueira.com blog  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//robertnogueira.com/blog/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654) report.  Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Comment: Did that work? If so, accept the answer that was correct or helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/faq